# How to populate a rails simple_form select box using an index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

hopefully this isn't too complicated..

So I have a model with LOTS of attributes, which I've decided to store as indexes in the database which refer to an constant at the model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   STATUS_CHOICES = %w( single relationship married divorced complicated open )
   etc...
```

In my form, I'm doing this right now:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |p|
  = dp.input :relationship_status, :required => true, :collection => Datingprofile::STATUS_CHOICES
```

This displays the collection very well, but of course, the value needs to be set from the index coming through from the model. How would I set the values on the collection to correspond to the correct index of the STATUS_CHOICES array?

*Update: Going to re-architect this to make the enum-ed attribs actual AD objects*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to implement this constants of hashes instead of arrays, which affords the simplicity of one model without the complexity of dealing with indexes..I'll store the hash keys and use the values only in the view.

Whee!!

Answer (score 6):

**model**

some sort of constant hash:

```
HASH_NAME = {
 0 => "Choose:",
1 => "On-Campus Recruiting - CSO",·
2 => "CSO Staff Referral",
3 => "Faculty Contact",·
4 => "Career Day",·
5 => "CSO Summer Job Listing",·
6 => "Alumni Contact",·
7 => "Personal Contact",·
8 => "Other"·
}
```

-- view

```
<%= f.input :some_field, :collection => Model::HASH_NAME.sort.map {|k,v| [v,k]} %>
```

This would output nice select with select-value as hash key and select-name as hash value, such as:

```
<select id="form_application_job_source" class="select required" name="form_application[job_source]">
<option value="0">Choose:</option>
<option value="1">On-Campus Recruiting - CSO</option>
<option value="2">CSO Staff Referral</option>
<option value="3">Faculty Contact</option>
<option value="4">Career Day</option>
<option value="5">CSO Summer Job Listing</option>
<option value="6">Alumni Contact</option>
<option selected="selected" value="7">Personal Contact</option>
<option value="8">Other</option>
</select>
```

Now, if you select say 'On-Campus Recruiting - CSO' from the dropdown, the value that would be stored is : 1

To show it in the view as 'On-Campus Recruiting - CSO' you would have to create a small return function like so in the model itself :

```
def return_paper_type
    HASH_NAME[id]
  end
```

In the view, it would be like this : `<%= @instancevariable.return_paper_type %>`

Comment: Where do I add the first Hash? In model file?

Comment: @Cybergenie Yes, you have to add the hash in the model file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply bro. I will post my result and like upvote your answer if it works now :)

Comment: It will work. Also, I can edit my answer to also reflect what you have to do if you need to get the "Text Value" in the view too.

Comment: Thanks will see if I can fix this myself :D.. Just a small question Sankalp. What are k,v and v,k doing here: HASH_NAME.sort.map {|k,v| [v,k]} %>. Sorry I am a beginner here dude.

Comment: They are just variables you can use anything you like instead of them.

Comment: I am not able to understand the error because of the formatting. Please format it and post again.

Comment: Guys try Sankalp's answer. So easy to implement and does not require any Gems. Just upvoted his answer too :D

Comment: Boss a small question related to your code. The options from the Hash are shown correctly in the form. But when data is saved into my table, it is saved as "1" or "2" when I choose Kraft Paper or Thermal Paper. How to solve this small issue?

Comment: It will save the value as 1 and 2 only as that is the value that is going to the database and this is the correct way. To show the value in the view, you have to make a small return function. I am updating my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hhaha, just tried your updated return function and it works AWESOME!! It was a little tricky at first but now I see how simple it is man. You are a great Dev :)

Comment: Bro just ran into a small problem while returning the object form HASH using def return_paper_type HASH_NAME[id] end. The id is storing properly for the item selected in the view form. But only the first object in from the HashMap list is being generated in the view form. The database is storing the correct updated value, but is not reflected in the view. No error. Any idea boss?

Answer (score 2):

One way to quickly solve this would be to make the collection the enumerated indices for the option element values, then use the STATUS_CHOICES array to get the labels using :label_method.

```
= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |p|
  = dp.input :relationship_status, :required => true, :collection =>  0..Datingprofile::STATUS_CHOICES.length, :label_method => lambda { |i| Datingprofile::STATUS_CHOICES[i] }
```

References:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/test/inputs/collection_select_input_test.rb#L141

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'enum_help'
```

And then execute:

```
$ bundle
```

In model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum relationship_status:{single: 0,relationship:1, married:2, divorced:3, complicated:4, open:5}
   etc...
```

In _form.html.erb using simple_form:

```
<%= f.input :relationship_status %>
```

For more information: https://github.com/zmbacker/enum_help